# php elegance keys unsetting

Tags: php, arrays, array-unset

I need to remove from an array some keys.

```
$array = array('a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => 'c');
unset($array['a']);
unset($array['b']);
```

How can I do this more elegance? Maybe there is a function like this `array_keys_unset('a', 'b')`?
I don't need `array_values` or `foreach`. I only want to know is it possible.
Thank you in advance. Sorry for my english and childlike question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do that with single call to `unset` as:

```
unset($array['a'],$array['b']);
```

Comment: Here I was writing a function.  +1

Comment: @Stephen: Language constructs > functions :P

Answer (score 5):

`unset()` is as simple as it gets, but as another solution how about this?

```
$keys_to_remove = array_flip(array('a', 'b'));
$array = array_diff_key($array, $keys_to_remove);
```

Put into a function:

```
function array_unset_keys(array $input, $keys) {
    if (!is_array($keys))
        $keys = array($keys => 0);
    else
        $keys = array_flip($keys);

    return array_diff_key($input, $keys);
}

$array = array_unset_keys($array, array('a', 'b'));
```

Or you could even make it `unset()`-like by passing it a variable number of arguments, like this:

```
function array_unset_keys(array $input) {
    if (func_num_args() == 1)
        return $input;

    $keys = array_flip(array_slice(func_get_args(), 1));

    return array_diff_key($input, $keys);
}

$array = array_unset_keys($array, 'a', 'b');
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would just do this if I had a long / arbitrary list of keys to set:

```
foreach (array('a', 'b') as $key) unset($array[$key]);
```

You could use a combination of array functions like `array_diff_key()`, but I think the above is the easiest to remember.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)?

Note that you can do `unset($array['a'], $array['b']);`

You could also write a function like the one you suggested, but I'd use an array instead of variable parameters.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no predefined function like `array_keys_unset`.

You could either pass [`unset`](http://php.net/unset) multiple variables:

```
unset($array['a'], $array['b']);
```

Or you write such a `array_keys_unset` yourself:

```
function array_keys_unset(array &$arr) {
    foreach (array_slice(func_get_args(), 1) as $key) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

The call of that function would then be similar to yours:

```
array_keys_unset($array, 'a', 'b');
```

Comment: +1 Cleanest of all solutions though I hate PHP's array_xxx method nomenclature. Let's call it something else ... e.g. `strip_keys`.